# Hide and show buttons need to be "show" first

Tags: html, css, button, toggle, show

I want to make some show/hide button, but I need the element to be invisible first and only visible after pushing the button - just the opposite from how it is now:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
  var x = document.getElementById("navigationList");

  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation_bar">
  <button class="hamburger" onclick="myFunction(this)">
         <div class="bar1"></div>
         <div class="bar2"></div>
     </button>
  <div id="navigationList">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="home_1_t.html">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming soon.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming soon.html">products</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming soon.html">services</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming soon.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just place a style attribute with the value "display: none" in your navigation List.

Also you are only checking string so "=="(double equal) should work instead of "===".

```
<div id="navigationList" style="display : none;">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In css, first make #navigationList to none as below:

```
<style>#navigationList{display:none;} </style>

<script>

function myFunction(x) {

   x.classList.toggle("change");

   var x = document.getElementById("navigationList");

    if (x.style.display === "block") {

      x.style.display = "none";

    } else {

       x.style.display = "block";  
      }

  }

</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

This should to the job:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("navigationList");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="navigation_bar">
  <!-- had to correct a mistyped class name -->
  <button class="hamburger" onclick="myFunction()">Toggle-Button</button>
  <!-- the parameter "x" is not needed here -->
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  </button>
  <div id="navigationList" style="display: none;">
    <ul>
      <li><a class="active" href="home_1_t.html">home</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming soon.html">about</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming soon.html">products</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming soon.html">services</a></li>
      <li><a href="coming soon.html">contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your initial click won't work there is no style attribute with value to check. Hence it will fail on first time.

Comment: Totally forgot about that! Thank you, I corrected my answer. @ARJUN